# Are Godel's incompleteness theorems proven non-trivial?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

Godel's incompleteness theorem states there will be unprovable statements in some language.  Can it be proven that the unprovable statements in some language $F$ are **necessarily** not just "trivially unprovable" statements such as:

The axioms themselves (statements taken to be true in the absence of proof) Note: Servaes has kindly advised advised these are considered "trivially provable" and therefore not applicable - fine.

Theorems of the metatheory (e.g. True is True; True is not False) Note: Noah Schweber has advised these are trivial theorems and therefore not applicable - fine.

Illogical statements (statements whose negation requires the statement be true e.g. the liar paradox) Note: Please see longer footnote below.

"Ungrounded statements" as described by Saul Kripke [here][1] (Note: I've this category added at a later date)

Any other cases of "trivially unprovable" statements which I haven't identified.

Clearly we have the category "Proof that something, which is not a theorem of the axioms, does not exist." into which falls the example of the continuum hypothesis in ZFC which is thought unlikely to fit into any of the above categories - so it would seem likely that there must be non-trivial statements in **some** languages which are unprovable, but is it proven, or provable, that there **necessarily** exist unprovable statements not fitting into any of these "trivial" categories, in every language?
(Note bolding added later as the meaning was missed by some readers before)

What I'm trying to do here, is to categorise in some sense the types of unprovable statements and circumstances in which they arise.

**Note with respect to Illogical Statements:**
In response to advice I'm defining more explicitly what I consider an illogical statement and why I think the Liar Paradox is one.  Please correct any misconception!

Definition: An illogical statement is a statement whose truth value is the inverse of its own truth value.

1: (Sentence $s_1$ is illogical if $s_1\implies\neg s_1$ or $\neg s_1\implies s_1$)

2: Let $s_1$ be the Liar Paradox "This sentence is false.".

3: Rewriting 2: $s_1\implies \neg s_1$

4: From 3,1: $\implies s_1$ is illogical.

**And for the modified Liar:**
Modified Liar: This sentence is unprovable:

5: Let $s_2$ be "This sentence is unprovable."

6: $(s_2\implies s_2)\implies\neg s_2$

7: $s_2\implies\neg s_2$

8: From 7,1: $\implies s_2$ is illogical.

Please don't shower the question with downvotes... I'm still learning!  Give me a chance to improve the question.

Comment: Aren't the axioms of a language trivially provable? That is, simply their statement constitutes a proof within the language.

Comment: Goodstein's theorem is known to be undecidable in PA, and it doesn't appear to me to be in any of the categories you mentioned.

Comment: [G's incompleteness theorem](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) "manufacture" unprovable sentences (relative to the theory considered) that belong to no one of your cases.

Comment: First of all, the axioms *are* provable in the axiom system - they are just one-line proofs. Godel is about what is provable in an axiom system, and in an axiom system, the axioms are proven. (2) Godel finds a statement in the theory which can't be proven. The statement has a *meta-meaning* -  we want it to be true to match our intuition about the natural numbers - but it is neither true nor false in the axiom system. The axiom system just doesn't specify our intuition about the natural numbers enough.

Comment: @Servaes I assume so; but I just wanted to verify the semantics of what the term *proveable* means because axioms are taken to be true in the absence of *proof* and as such there is an argument that they are *unproveable*. So I was just being thorough in making sure we're all using the same language.

Comment: @MJD Thanks for that example. Interestingly Goodenstein theorem is exactly equivalent to the consistency of Peano Arithmetic. This is what I'm trying to learn about here... what exactly is the nature of these unprovable sentences and how can we categorise them. I find it very interesting that this particular example is exactly equivalent to the consistency of the system in which it is unprovable. What I'm trying to determine is whether there are some bounds on the nature of sentences that are unprovable.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for that. Are there any such examples which I can use to categorise and understand the nature of such statements, which do not require weeks of intensive research to understand?

Comment: In a certain sense, there are none "trivial"; G's original unprovable sentence is quite "simple" from the meta-theory point of view (see Noah's answer) but as an "arithmetical formula" is totally "unmanageable". Further examples, like Goodstein or Paris_harrington are mathematically "significant" sentences, but their unprovability is a highly technical result.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but in the spirit of the question, if Goldstein is the strongest unprovable statement in Peano then this creates some significant hope in relation to what some system of mathematics can accomplish since it is exactly equivalent to the consistency of Peano arithmetic.  If it's not possible to find better statements than Goldstein, then it's possible that the only unprovable statements in a language $F$ are illogical statements and the consistency of the language itself. Or can you provide a counterexample to this hypothesis?

Comment: @RobertFrost As my answer states, given any reasonable theory $T$ there will be a Diophantine equation $E$ such that the sentence "$E$ has no solutions" is neither provable nor disprovable by $T$. This is about as concrete as it gets. Another response: for any reasonable $T$, we can find a $\varphi$ which is not decidable from $T$, but such that neither $T+\varphi$ nor $T+\neg\varphi$ proves $Con(T)$ (HINT: otherwise $T+\neg Con(T)$ would be complete . . .). And, by the way, you still haven't defended your claim of illogicality in any real way!

Comment: Thanks I'm starting to get it now.  Are there generally multiple , non-equivalent $E$ such that the sentence "$E$ has no solutions" is neither provable nor disprovable by $T$ or just some special case?  What is the problem with $T + $ negation of $Con(T)$ being complete? I guess it means the theory is inconsistent?

Comment: What would a valid defence of my claim of illogicality have to include? Surely introducing a statement whose truth depends on its own falsehood, allows proof that black is white?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems you are confused about the statement of Godel's theorem:

> If $T$ is a "reasonable" first-order theory, then there is a first-order sentence $\varphi$ in the language of $T$ such that neither $\varphi$ nor $\neg\varphi$ is provable in $T$.

None of the examples you give are examples of such a sentence!

- The axioms of a theory $T$ **are** provable in $T$.
- Statements like "This statement is false" **cannot** be expressed in first-order logic.
- I'm not sure what "True is true" means, but if you're going to express it in first-order logic, it would presumably be "$\top\iff \top$," which is indeed a theorem, as is "$\neg(\top\iff\bot)$."

---

I think the following might help explain why Godel isn't trivial:

Let's work with the theory $PA$ (Peano arithmetic) for simplicity. It's language is $\{+, \times, <, 0, 1\}$, which means that a *first-order sentence* in this language is built out of

- Those symbols,
- variables - which are interpreted as ranging over *numbers*,
- quantifiers $\exists$ and $\forall$ - again, ranging over *numbers*,
- Booleans $\wedge, \vee, \implies$, and $\neg$,
- and okay fine we also want parentheses "$($" and "$)$".

At this point it's a good exercise to sit down and try to express "This statement is false" in this way. You'll quickly find that it seems to be impossible: the language simply isn't expressive enough to talk about sentences and truth. Now, the genius of Godel's proof is the realization that actually the language of arithmetic **can** talk about sentences and provability (if not truth) in an indirect-but-still-powerful way, via **Godel numbering**. And then a *modified* version of the Liar paradox - specifically, the sentence $$\mbox{"This sentence is not provable in $PA$"}$$ (or better yet, Rosser's variation - "For every $PA$-proof of this sentence, there is a shorter $T$-disproof of this sentence") - lets us show that $PA$ is incomplete.

But this is **extremely non-trivial**, since at the outset it's not clear at all how to form sentences which talk about sentences, let alone sentences which talk about *themselves*, in the very narrow first-order language of $PA$!

---

**EDIT, in reply to your comments below**: Let's start with your last comment. The notion of "proof" in Godel's theorem is "proof *from the axioms of $T$*"; there is simply no relevant notion of ex nihilo proof. So yes, the axioms *of $T$* are trivially provable *from $T$*.

This is a good point, though - in my above formulation of the Godel sentence, I used "prove" as shorthand for "prove *in $PA$*," which I should not have done. I've fixed it now.

As to expressing the Liar Paradox in the language of arithmetic - no, those don't work, for a number of reasons:

- First, a very minor point: "$x\not=x$" and "$x=y\iff x\not=y$" aren't *sentences*, they're *formulas* - they have free variables. So you'd need to quantify them out first - e.g. "$\forall x(x\not=x)$," or similarly.
- Second, those sentences (even when made into genuine sentences) aren't *paradoxical*, they're just *wrong*. Think about it: "$0\not=0$" isn't a paradox, it's just a false statement.
- Third, more fundamentally, you seem to be treating the variables as ranging over *sentences* (motivating e.g. "$x\not=x$" as "a sentence is not equal to itself"). But they don't do this: the variables range only over *numbers*.
- Fourth, *even if they did* range over sentences (and they can be treated as doing so in certain contexts, via Godel number, if we're careful), there's nothing forcing the variable "$x$" in "$x\not=x$" to refer to the formula "$x\not=x$" itself - and self-reference is **critical** to the Liar Paradox. "This statement is false" is a paradox; "some other statement is false" isn't, really.

Finally, there's your objection that the Godel sentence is "illogical." I'm not really sure what that means, but I think you're still assuming that the language of arithmetic is broader than it actually is. The Godel sentence (and its many variations) is just a statement about natural numbers; the fact that it has any self-referential character at all is *surprising*. And we can do even more concretely: as a corollary of the [**MRDP theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem), as long as $T$ is a true, computably axiomatizable theory, there is a *Diophantine equation* $E_T$ such that

- $E_T$ has no solutions, but
- $T$ cannot prove "$E_T$ has no solutions."

This is about as concrete as it gets; I don't know any way that Diophantine equations are "illogical." *Recall: a Diophantine equation is an equation of the form $p(x_1, . . . , x_n)=q(x_1, . . . , x_n)$ where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials with natural number coefficients; and a solution to a Diophantine equation is a set of natural numbers which solves it.*

In fact, the construction of $E_T$ from $T$ is **effective**: there is a computable function $f$ such that, if $e$ is a code (i.e. Turing machine index) for a true computably axiomatizable theory $T$ in the language of arithmetic, then $f(e)$ is a code for a Diophantine equation which has no solutions but which $T$ can't prove has no solutions.

**Tl;dr**: I think you should go back and read the proof of Godel's theorem, and the surrounding definitions in mathematical logic, *carefully*. It is not trivial, nor is the Godel sentence illogical. Peter Smith's book does a very good job explicating it.

Comment: An aside: in the first part of my answer I implied that "$\top$" and "$\bot$" are symbols in first-order logic, yet they're missing from my description of first-order logic in the second part of my answer. This is fine, though: we can treat "$\top$" as an abbreviation for "$\forall x(x=x)$," and similarly for "$\bot$".

Comment: Great reply, thank-you. Is the liar paradox not easy to state in Peano arithmetic? My attempt would simply be $x\neq x$, or in a more complex but perhaps more intuitive form $x=y \leftrightarrow x\neq y$ because the liar paradox is fundamentally a statement whose truth requires its own negation.  But focusing on the question of proving rigorously that the unprovable statements aren't simply the paradoxical or illogical ones - does your answer address this? I may be being daft. e.g. are there examples of *logical* statements which have been demonstrated unproveable in Peano arithmetic?

Comment: And I know this is semantics, but I am assuming the axioms count as "provable" even though their truth is taken as a given in the absence of proof.  I just want to be clear when you say "unproveable", the axioms don't fall into this category. (Because I can only understand accurately your modified version of the liar paradox with the answer to this question.)

Comment: @RobertFrost See my edit. (Too long for comment boxes.)

Comment: "This statement is false" implies that its own truth value is equal to the negation of its own truth value therefore it implies $\exists x (x\neq x)$.  Surely illogical statements should not be permitted? Every statement inherently asserts its own truth i.e. $x=y$ implies "$x=y$ *is true*" without explicitly requiring the "is true". So for a statement to assert its own falsehood asserts $x\neq x$.

Comment: As for the "This statement is unprovable".  This statement explicity declares itself to be an axiom.  Since if it is unprovable then its negation is unprovable so to permit such a statement is to declare it true in the absence of proof, making it an axiom. This appears to then be conflated with firstly the liar paradox and secondly, the notion of what is provable from *the axioms* when it must itself be an axiom. I'm concerned that all these examples have illogicality in them.  Your other examples, it looks like I'll have to do some pretty serious work to get to grips with those!

Comment: @RobertFrost No, this is incorrect. While it is true that "This statement is false" implies "$\exists x(x\not=x)$" (or at least, it *would* be true if "This statement is false" could be expressed as a first-order sentence), it is **not true** that "$\exists x(x\not=x)$" is *equivalent* (in any nice sense) to "This statement is false." The sentence "$\exists x(x\not=x)$" is straightforwardly *false*; the sentence "This statement is false" is *paradoxical*. Finally, for the *third* time, variables in first-order logic range over *numbers*, not *sentences*. (Cont'd)

Comment: Also, I have no idea what "illogical" means in this context. **All the sentences involved here are sentences about natural numbers!** And the Godel sentence *does not* declare itself to be an axiom; "axiom" is a precise term, and refers *only* to the specific elements of the theory $T$. There is a *relation* to the Liar paradox, but they're quite different things.

Comment: ok I was hoping numbers could be mapped to truth values eg 1 to true and 0 to false but clearly this is naughty!  Let me see if I can construct it with numbers.

Comment: "I'm concerned that these examples have illogicality in them." This sentence, insofar as it means anything, is false. You should actually *read* Godel's proof (or better yet, one of the modern explanations thereof) before dismissing it as "trivial" or the sentences involved as "illogical." I think we've temporarily reached the point of diminishing returns, so I'm going to bow out for now, but let me end with one exercise: if you **really** think "$\exists x(x\not=x)$" is a formulation of the Liar, then you should be able to deduce a contradiction in $PA$ from it *or its negation*. (cont'd)

Comment: So try to prove "$0=1$" starting from "$\neg\exists x(x\not=x)$." Given that the informal proof of "$0=1$" from the negation of the Liar is a two-line proof by contradiction, you should be able to do a similar thing here; but you'll quickly find that you can't.

Comment: Ok I'll give that a try and thanks for all your help. By the way I'm not dismissing anything or dismissing anything as "trivial" I'm trying to probe at the logic to find the flaw (which I assume I will ultimately find in my own reasoning).

Comment: OK, let's code sentences by numbers (which we can do - Godel numbering) and assume we had some way to express "is true" (which we **don't** - Tarski proved this - but oh well). Then you'd be interested in the sentence "$\exists x (TV(x)\not=TV(x))$" (where "$TV()$" means "truth value of"). However, this *still* isn't the Liar - it's simply a false statement! The Liar says **I am false**, and that self-reference is crucial. Now, via the Fixed Point Theorem, we *could* get a sentence $p$ such that $PA$ proved $p\iff (TV(p)=\bot)$, and this $p$ would be (essentially) the Liar; (cont'd)

Comment: but that's far from what you wrote. Think about converting it to English: "There is some sentence which is true iff it is false" is at best asserting the *existence* of the Liar, but it's not the Liar itself. (Meanwhile, the above argument - together with the usual analysis of the Liar - shows that if $PA$ is consistent, then "$TV$" **can't** be expressed! This is Tarski's Undefinability Theorem. The surprising result of Godel was that provability-from-$PA$ **can** be expressed, unlike truth.)

Comment: Yes I see your logic.  Would you argue that $\exists x (x=5)$ is not equivalent to the sentence $x=5$ ?  Since they seem equivalent to me.  What do you make of the following sentence?  Every statement inherently declares its own existence.

Comment: @RobertFrost Those two statements certainly *aren't* the same - "$\exists x(x=5)$" is certainly a true statement about the natural numbers, but whether "$x=5$" is true or not depends on what variable assignment you use (google "free variable"). Finally, I'm not sure what you mean by "every statement inherently declares its own existence." I would **strongly** suggest that you try to make all the notions you're using here - "illogical," "inherently declares," etc. - *precise.* Mathematical logic is, like the rest of mathematics, an *exact* subject.

Comment: A statement declares its own existence I guess is $s \implies \exists s \for all sentences s$.  Not sure if or how this is proven?  Illogical sentences I defined in the question but more formally a sentence $s$ is illogical iff $\not s \Leftrightarrow s$ - which both the liar paradox and the modified liar satisfy.

Comment: $s \implies \exists s$ $\forall$ sentences $s$

Comment: @RobertFrost First of all, note that "$s\implies \exists s$" isn't first-order - you're quantifying over *sentences* here. More importantly, "$\exists s$" isn't a well-formed formula - the existential quantifier has to *bind* something (as in "$\exists s(...)$"). Also, $s$ is being treated as free on the left, and bound on the right - it doesn't refer to the same thing! So that's basically meaningless. Second, while the Liar does satisfy $\neg s\iff s$, the "modified Liar" (I presume you mean the Godel sentence?) does **not** - it is true (assuming $PA$ is consistent) (cont'd)

Comment: and it is provable in $PA+Con(PA)$; it's just not provable in $PA$ alone. So, I'll reiterate: **the Godel sentence $\varphi$ is not illogical**. I **really really strongly** suggest looking at the actual *proof* to see how it's constructed.

Comment: Thanks for your help in this.  When you say "you're quantifying over sentences" and "the existential quantifier has to bind something" sadly you're hinting at issues you clearly understand but I have no experience of. Your objection to the statement "a sentence inherently declares its own existence" is an objection to something which is obviously self-evidently true, so any objection to it can only be a limitation of the theory in which you're operating - not that that is a criticism of you, nor necessarily of the theory; just that the statement is clearly true in the real world.

Comment: My attempt to rewrite it in first order logic would be $s\implies\exists s: (s\implies s)$.

Comment: What's more I think you're wrong to say "this statement is false" does not inherently declare its own truth value to be the negation of its of truth value.  If we number "this statement is false" as sentence 1 then sentence 1 is true if and only iff sentence 1 is true.  Yet sentence 1 declares that sentence 1 is false. Therefore sentence 1 is true if and only if "sentence 1 is false" is true.  Does this not suggest that $\exists x(x\neq x)$ (which is obviously not permitted) would be the Peano equivalent of the Liar?

Comment: I am however VERY interested in your description of it being unprovable that diophantine equations have no solutions. I wonder if there may be profound limits on the nature of unprovable statements in strong theories such as Peano, for example that they may be limited to statements of the form that something "does not exist".